# PHP, Regex last occurance of one (or more) string

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

Okay - this has boggled me for days.  I've tried regex with negative lookahead, but to no avail.

Basically, in PHP, I need to parse conversation threads and extract the LAST occurrence of http links that can occur by itself, or in a consecutive group of 2 or more.    So, in example 1, it should return the last link, but in example 2, it should return the last 3 links.

I don’t need to achieve this with a single regex, but I’m not sure what other approaches to try.  Any help would be appreciated!!

### EXAMPLE 1:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
>
> http://sample.com/12345.png
>
> In pharetra elementum dui vel pretium. Quisque rutrum mauris vitae
>   turpis hendrerit facilisis. Sed ultrices imperdiet ornare.
>
> http://sample.com/13578.png

---

### EXAMPLE 2:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
>
> http://sample.com/12345.png
>
> In pharetra elementum dui vel pretium. Quisque rutrum mauris vitae
>   turpis hendrerit facilisis. Sed ultrices imperdiet ornare.
>
> http://sample.com/24689.png
>  http://sample.com/13578.png
>   http://sample.com/98761.png

---

Comment: Too many links and images. Write your question so that you don't rely on the images and links

Comment: @Andreas read the question again. (I also thought the same though ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Split your Text on the delimiter `\s`.

```
$resultArray = preg_split("@\s@", $conversation)
```

on example:

```
$conversation = "Hallo, http://1.de text http://2.de\r\nhttp://3.de Hello";
```

(This will produce something like this as intermediate result:)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hallo,
    [1] => http://1.de
    [2] => text
    [3] => http://2.de
    [4] => 
    [5] => http://3.de
    [6] => Hello
)
```

2.) Finally, reverse iterate over the result array. Start "matching", if the result starts with "http://" - stop matching if you encounter anything else, Ignore Empty lines as well as lines with whitespaces only.:

```
$conversation = "Hallo, http://1.de text http://2.de\r\nhttp://3.de Hello";
$resultArray = preg_split("@\s@", $conversation);
$result = array();

$matching = false;
for ($i = count($resultArray)-1; $i >= 0; $i--){
    if (preg_match("@http:\/\/@", $resultArray[$i])){
      $matching=true;
      $result[] = $resultArray[$i];  
    } else if (preg_match("@^\s*$@", $resultArray[$i])){
       //ignore this bad boy
    }else{
        if ($matching){
            break;
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_reverse($result));
echo "</pre>";
```

yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://2.de
    [1] => http://3.de
)
```